# Stripe subscription - update with prorate disabled

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to manage subscriptions, and I have a php function for upgrading a user's subscription. The current code is as follows:

```
$stripe_subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($stripe_subscription_data->id);
$stripe_subscription->plan = $request->plan;
$stripe_subscription->save();
```

The existing code works, but I'm trying to tell Stripe not to prorate the subscriptions. According to [Stripe's API](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations#disable-prorations), I can use the update function and set prorate to false. [Their example code looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJmGp.png). As such I revised the code to this:

```
$stripe_subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($stripe_subscription_data->id);
\Stripe\Subscription::update($stripe_subscription_data->id, array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "id" => $stripe_subscription->items->data[0]->id,
            "plan" => $request->plan,
            ),
        ),
    "prorate" => false,
));
$stripe_subscription->save();
```

When I use the function now, I get the error:

> "Call to undefined method Stripe\Subscription::update()"

I checked Stripe's php plug-in [changelog](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3130---2016-05-04) and I'm running version 3.14 which should have the update function defined. Furthermore, it has no problem with the retrieve method which was defined in the same update so I don't see how I can have one undefined but not the other.

**How can I update the subscription with "prorate" set to false, either by changing my original code or fixing the undefined error?**

Comment: in the code from the example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJmGp.png) there is a key/val for item id (id) but your code is missing that key/val. ... 'id' => $subscription-> ...

Comment: @Ggg I added "id" into the query. No change.

Comment: in your stripe dashboard, what is the api version there?

Comment: Dashboard says the version is is 2016-06-15

Comment: the plan you are upgrading in your code example, was it a free plan that will upgrade to a paid one?

Comment: It was a paid plan, being charged once a month, to another paid plan with a different rate, being charged once every three months.

Comment: just as a test, would you be willing to change your api version in your dashboard and re-run your code? If it doesnt fix it, you will have 30 days to revert it

Comment: I would not recommend changing your Stripe API version without extensive testing with any other software you have connected to the API as it can break things unexpectedly. If you want to change the API version for a single request, [there's an API feature for this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/#versioning). In this case, the error is coming from the PHP library, not the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what's going on—that changelog isn't *quite* correct. It looks like the `update` method is added in version **3.15.0** of the PHP library:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/commit/51d4ece822c4db166adbe2be167564d84bce6222

I will also note that this version is quite old, and I'd recommend upgrading to the latest version. If you're on an older version of PHP (which is not recommended for production for of lack of security patches) then you can use up to version 5.9.2:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600---2018-02-07